# Reflection to access values that are nested classes

Tags: java, reflection

I know it is bad code design, but as a temporary hack...

I need to access a private map where the values are initializations of a static nested class. In the following example, I want to access each value of myMap from a different package.

```
package belongs.to.someone.else

public class SOExample {
    private Map<String, NestedClass> myMap;

    static class NestedClass {
        final int data;
        NestedClass(final int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public void populateMyMap(){
        for(int i=0; i<100;  i++){
            this.myMap.put(Integer.toString(i), new NestedClass(i));
        }
    }
}
```

But I seem to run into a chicken and egg problem when trying to set the SOExample.myMap field to accessible. I get "cannot be accessed from outside of package" error for the `SOExample.NestedClass` values in the last statement.

```
package belongs.to.me
public class SOExampleMyPackage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        SOExample example = new SOExample();
        example.populateMyMap();

        // Make the example.myMap field accessible
        Field f = example.getClass().getDeclaredField("myMap");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        // Next line throws error
        Map<String, SOExample.NestedClass> myMapHere = (Map<String, SOExample.NestedClass>) f.get(example);
    }
}
```

I appreciate any ideas about how to solve this problem.

Comment: How are you going to use `myMapHere`? Compiler is right by telling you that you can't access `NestedClass` via `SOExample.NestedClass` since `NestedClass` is package private.

Comment: Is it possible that `NestedClass` actually implements some public interface which contains methods you are interested in? In that case you could use `Map<String, ThatInterface>` or `Map<String, ? extends ThatInterface>`.

Comment: @Pshemo myMap is has about 500k values that are created through a very slow discrete event simulation that can take a day to converge. We want to serialize myMap and have that data on hand so that we can quickly deserialize it.

Comment: @Phesmo, unfortunately NestedClass does not implement a public interface.

Comment: @Phesmo, followup to my first comment. Since NestedClass can't be serialized, the idea is access it and pull out the primitive field that can be.

Comment: You can try serializing it to something like JSON (some parsers don't need `Serializable` interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get compile time error because nested class is not accessible.

The only thing you can do is to avoid using references of this class:

```
Field f = example.getClass().getDeclaredField("myMap");
f.setAccessible(true);
Map map = (Map) f.get(example);
Object obj = map.get("1");
```

You can access fields and invoke methods on the `obj` instance with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

@AdamSkywalker supplied the correct approach. I am posting the final working example just for completeness.

```
public class SOExampleMyPackage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        SOExample example = new SOExample();
        example.populateMyMap();

        // Make the example.myMap field accessible
        Field f = example.getClass().getDeclaredField("myMap");
        f.setAccessible(true);

        /////
        //SOLUTION start
        /////
        Map<String, Object> myMapHere = (Map<String, Object>) f.get(example);

        // Loop through entries and reflect out the values
        Map<String, Integer> finalMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String k: myMapHere.keySet()){
            Field f2 = myMapHere.get(k).getClass().getDeclaredField("data");
            f2.setAccessible(true);
            finalMap.put(k, (Integer) f2.get(myMapHere.get(k)));
        }
        /////
        //SOLUTION end
        /////

        // Test it all
        for (String k: finalMap.keySet()){
            System.out.println("Key: " + k + " Value: " + finalMap.get(k));
        }
    }
}
```